# SQL Multiple joins with OR condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a following tables:

TableA

- id
- name

TableB

- id
- tableA_id

TableC

- id
- tableA_id

So tables B and C have `tableA_id` fk.

I need a query which will return all id-s from TableA that have reference in either TableB or TableC.

If I do standard join, it will return only values that have reference in both tables B and C.

I could do this using two queries, one joins B, other joins C and use UNION to merge results, but I dont want to write same query twice.

Is there a way to achieve this 'OR' JOIN??

Comment: You can use EXISTS or 2 outer joins and check for at least 1 non null returned value from a/b (coalesce would work there).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLEA.ID_A, TABLEA.NAME 
FROM TABLEA,TABLEB,TABLEC 
WHERE TABLEA.ID_A = TABLEB.ID_A AND TABLEA.ID_A = TABLEC.ID_A
```

Using DISTINCT TAG you eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TableA,
    TableB,
    TableC
WHERE
    TableA.id = TableB.tableA_id
    OR TableA.id = TableC.tableA_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use left outer joins and checks for the ids:

```
SELECT a.id FROM A a 
    LEFT JOIN B b ON a.id = b.tableA_id LEFT JOIN C c ON a.id = c.tableA_id
WHERE b.id IS NOT NULL OR c.id IS NOT NULL
```